# Imprimir lista contendo intervalo, crescente e decrescente, contendo todos os números entre dois valores digitados pelo usuário - Python

Tags: python

Enunciado completo da questão:
Faça um programa para ler repetidamente dois números naturais A e B maiores que zero. Para cada leitura de A e B o programa deve imprimir, no formato de uma lista, a sequência crescente de números do intervalo entre A e B se A < B, ou a sequência decrescente se A ≥ B. O programa finaliza a execução quando a leitura de A ou B forem iguais a zero.

```
      while (True):
      A,B = input("Digite A e B: ").split( )
      if (A == "0") or (B == "0"):
         print("Fim.")
         break
      if ("A" < "B"):
        numeros = [A, B]
        print("Sequencia:",sorted(numeros))
      elif ("A" > "B") or ("A" == "B"):
        numeros = [A, B]
        print("Sequencia:",sorted(numeros, reverse = True))
```

Somente consegui imprimir a lista contendo os valores "A" e "B" digitados pelo usuário. Estou com dificuldade em como fazer para imprimir o intervalo, crescente e decrescente, com todos os números entre "A" e "B". Pensei nas funções range e count, mas não sei como atribui-las nesse caso. Pesquisando não achei nada parecido.
Como poderia fazer isso?

OBS: Iniciante em python.

Comment: No segundo `if` e no `elif`, você está comparando os caracteres "A" e "B" e não as variáveis A e B. 
P.S.: também precisa rever o uso do `break`.

Comment: Não sei o porque complicar as coisas, veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/yQgAfd

Comment: Se puder usar `range`: https://ideone.com/TuSWek

Answer (score -1):

Tenta isso aqui:

```py
while True:
    #para o usuário não ficar confuso, use inputs diferentes
    A = int(input("Digite A: "))#você precisa converter em inteiro para iterar sobre
    if A <= 0:
        print("Fim.")
        break
    B = int(input("Digite B: "))
    if B <= 0:
        print("Fim.")
        break

    elif A >= B:#python já tem um operador de maior ou igual
        numeros = list(reversed(range(B, A)));
        #range automaticamente gera um "range" de números entre B e A
        #reversed inverte o "range"
        #list, converte o "range" invertido em uma  lista
        print("Sequencia:", numeros)

    else: #não existe outra possibilidade, só pode ser isso
        numeros = list(range(A, B));
        print("Sequencia:",numeros)
```